# Testing a Puppet custom function with RSpec, why can't I see facter variables?

Tags: rspec, puppet

According to http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_functions.html#using-facts-and-variables , I should be able to access facts by calling lookupvar

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:machinelist2, :type => :rvalue) do
    lookupvar('operatingsystem')
  end
end
```

Using this in spec, it returns nil.

```
context 'something' do
  let(:facts) {{:operatingsystem => 'blah'}}
  it "should return os" do
    result = scope.function_machinelist2([])
    result.should(eq('blah'))
  end
end
```

(and running spec...)
$ rspec

```
machinelist2 function
  should exist
  something
    should return os (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) machinelist2 function something should return os
     Failure/Error: result.should(eq('blah'))

       expected: "blah"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/parser/functions/machinelist2_spec.rb:17

Finished in 0.12478 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/parser/functions/machinelist2_spec.rb:15 # machinelist2 function something should return os
```

Even if I remove the let(:facts) entry, I would expect the facter variable to resolve to the current operating system.

It certainly does in my rspec-puppet tests for "regular" puppet code (class/module manifests)

**UPDATE:**
I missed the part of the doc that says:

> To use a fact about a client, use lookupvar('FACT NAME') instead of
>   Facter['FACT NAME'].value. If the fact does not exist, lookupvar
>   returns:

So, I tried the opposite, and used Facter['operatingsystem'].value .
This will return my current operating system, but I can't override it using let().

So, my question really is, HOW should I override facter variables to test custom functions that use them (facts)???

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across some examples and it seems obvious now that because of the "raw ruby" nature of the custom function, stubs will work!

e.g.

scope.stubs(:lookupvar).with("interfaces").returns('eth0,lo')

Here is a more complete example...

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'puppetlabs_spec_helper/puppetlabs_spec/puppet_internals'

describe "machinelist2 function" do
  let(:scope) { PuppetlabsSpec::PuppetInternals.scope }

  it "should exist" do
    Puppet::Parser::Functions.function("machinelist2").should == "function_machinelist2"
  end

context 'something' do
  it "should return os" do
    scope.stubs(:lookupvar).with("operatingsystem").returns('blah')
    result = scope.function_machinelist2([])
    result.should(eq('blah'))
  end
end
```

And sure enough...

```
rjames@ma-dt-rj:facts$ rspec

machinelist2 function
  should exist
  something
    should return os

Finished in 0.12552 seconds
2 examples, 0 failures
```

So... as long as I can rely on lookupvar() to work while running the actual puppet code (outside of rspec) then I think this should work just great.

Comment: Just so you know, `stubs` is from Mocha, not RSpec. Also, I still don't believe you're making any use of `let(:facts) ...` with this code. Does the example still pass when you remove the `let(:facts) ..` call?

Comment: Yes... sorry... let(:facts) is completely unused in my new case.  I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

I've got no insight into the fundamental puppet questions, but I suspect your `let` call is not having any effect because `let` methods are lazily evaluated and you don't appear to have utilized any of the custom matchers in the rspec-puppet gem that might utilize the `facts` method. In saying this, I'm assuming that neither `scope` nor `lookupvar` are from that gem.

Comment: I use that same let syntax with rspec-puppet all the time, happily.  In a manifest, a reference to $::operatingsystem would evaluate to whatever I set in the let in the test.
http://rspec-puppet.com/tutorial/

My question is around testing custom functions.  The listed way to lookup facter variables is by using lookupvar('operatingsystem').  But I can't seem to get that setup in the test in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and reference to the rspec-puppet gem. I've updated the answer and look forward to your feedback.